# Rouge or Rogue?

Tags: meaning, comparisons

Is there a difference between the two?

I want to write a sentence which says *Users Go Mad*, and would like to know the correct word to use here. Is this just American/British difference?

Comment: Doesn't *rouge* mean red?

Comment: *Rogue* and *mad* aren't the same thing anyway.

Comment: @Jim Didn't meant mad completely, it's like losing control and going destructive types..

Comment: @DamkerngT. Well, just searched and it said Red in French, though many have this doubt so posted as a question as I didn't got any reliable answer

Comment: [rouge](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rouge?q=rouge) vs [rogue](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rogue?q=rogue) vs [mad](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mad?q=mad)

Comment: I never imagined that there were people who thought they were the same thing. So all those times I see *rouge* in World of Warcraft are misunderstandings and not jokes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rouge is the French word for red. When someone orders a *rouge*, they mean red wine which in French translates to *le vin rouge*.

Rogue on the other hand can mean *scoundrel* or a *vagrant*

Comment: Rouge has also been an *English* word for "red" since the fifteenth century, 600 years ago. It started to be used to mean also the cosmetic "blusher" in the nineteenth century.

Answer (score 2):

[Rouge](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+rouge&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a):

(noun) a red powder or cream used as a cosmetic for coloring the cheeks or lips.

(verb) To color with rouge.

[Rogue](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+rogue&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a): (noun)

1. a dishonest or unprincipled man. ("you are a rogue and an embezzler")
   synonyms: scoundrel, villain, miscreant, reprobate, rascal, good-for-nothing, ne'er-do-well, wretch, knave
2. a person whose behavior one disapproves of but who is nonetheless likable or attractive (often used as a playful term of reproof).
   "Cenzo, you old rogue!" synonyms:   rascal, imp, devil, monkey
3. an elephant or other large wild animal driven away or living apart from the herd and having savage or **destructive tendencies**.

Comment: Susan,  typically we like to provide a link to the dictionary entry (or other source material) when citing them in answers.